# How can I iterate over an array and populate some cells with 1 if the array contains the value, and 0 if not ,in VBA or Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365, dynamic-arrays

I'm receiving from Wix an array with the courses selected by an user via a form.

Example of an array receive from Wix where an user selected 2 courses. This array is placed in a cell.

```
["VBA","Django"]
```

This above array is place inside a cell in my excel file from where I red the cell and populate a VBA array with the courses:

```
Dim data() As Variant
    Dim arrStr As String
    Dim dataItems As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim IndividualCourses(1 To 9) As String

    arrStr = Range("T3")
    arrStr = Replace(Replace(arrStr, "[", "{"), "]", "}")
    data = Application.Evaluate(arrStr)
    dataItems = Application.CountA(data)
    For i = 1 To dataItems
        IndividualCourses(i) = data(i)
    Next i
```

But the user can select between 1 and 10 courses. The array for all courses:

["JS","Python","VBA","Java","Spring","C++","C#",".NET","Django","CSS"]

I want, based on the array received from Wix, to put 1 in the cell of the courses present in the array and 0 in the other courses.

For example, this courses selected  ["VBA","Django"], it should put 1 in the VBA cell and 1 in the Django cell, and 0 in the remianing courses cells, because I want to see what courses an user has selected.

Any ideea for this complicated problem ?!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure how set you are on VBA, but depending on your version of Excel you can do this with dynamic arrays, for example:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=--ISNUMBER(FIND(""""&B1:K1&"""",A2))
```

---

***EDIT:***

As per @T.M. his valuable comment you can feed the 2nd parameter in `FIND()` a whole vertical range too:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=--ISNUMBER(FIND(""&B1:K1&"",A2:A4))
```

Comment: Not very set, I have started learning VBA last night.

Comment: @JvdV Nice; it's even possible to include a whole range of search items in column A via e.g. `=--ISNUMBER(FIND(""""&B1:K1&"""",A2:A100))` - *Hint: Take care to fill the whole caption row `B1:K1` with entries in order to prevent unwanted findings of a blank caption.*

Comment: Very nice @JvdV

Comment: @JvdV , the problem with drag and drop is B1:K1, this fields should be constants

Comment: You don't need to drag anything here @Byteis8bits. If you need to drag anything in the future. You can research (semi)absolute referencing. See [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)

Comment: Ok, JvdV, tks a lot

Comment: @JvdV, I don't get it. How can this formula populate more rows form me without drag and drop? I have inserted the formula in the first row, and now, what can I do?

Comment: With dynamic arrays (office365) the results will spill. If you see my edited answer I only used the mentioned formula in cell B2. Only if you do not have that version of Excel you'd need to drag a formula. In any such case you'd want to follow that link I included in my previous comment about semi absolute referencing. @byteis8bits