# How to optimize Excel formula automatically when drag and drop?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel formula that is looking for some courses in an array from a cell. In the picture below the column A2 is populated automatically from Wix with an array of courses that can contain 1 to 10 courses. And in regard to this array, the A:K columns are populated with 1 if the course exist in the array and 0 if not.

The formula is: =--ISNUMBER(FIND(""""&B2:K2&"""",A2))

The problem is when I fill a row and drag and drop to populate the formula to a great number of rows, the formula is changing. I need to keep B2:K2  the same, and only the A2 should change . If the row is A3, in the formula I should have =--ISNUMBER(FIND(""""&B2:K2&"""",A3)).

How can I automatically do this, because I have a large numbers if rows, and cannot right the formula to all rows?

[image]

Comment: Change the formula to: `=--ISNUMBER(FIND(""""&$B$2:$K$2&"""",A2))`, or if you copy then to the next row maybe `=--ISNUMBER(FIND(""""&$B2:$K2&"""",A2))`  The `$` sign indicates that that part of the cell reference should not change when copying the formula. ( BTW: I Hate drag and drop... )

Comment: Your result will be always shown in `B2:K2`? It seems you are using `Excel365` then you can use dymanic formulas.

Comment: Can you show some more dat to understand your requirements?

Comment: Yes, my formula will always be B2:K2

Comment: @byteis8bits Could you please try my answer.

Comment: **Note:** You don't need to drag anything. All you need is a single formula where you refer to all cells in the A column. See the comment by @T.M. under the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66354729/9758194). I have edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Harun24HR  , it's working fine!

Comment: @JvdV nice solution! Post it here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep `B2:K2` constant then lock them by `$` means absolute position like-

```
=--ISNUMBER(FIND(""""&$B$2:$K$2&"""",A2))
```

You can try below formula at once for whole range of data.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2:A4,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., '" & $B$1:$K$1 & "')]")),0,1)
```

[image]